Manage python environments with MacPorts
In win I was using anaconda and with conda activate I could easily manage isolated python environments that I can then used in any IDE etc.
How can I do the same with MacPorts? I know anaconda is also for macOS bui I read is quite incompatible with MacPorts. What about virtualenv package for MacPorts? what is the standard way to do this?

Where did you read about the incompatibility I use macports and conda albeit light use. virtualenv will be the same in all installs of python it does not set the version of python used. pyenv does that but I suspect does not work with macports.

If you don't want to use something like pyenv, you can just use port select and switch between them.
That may or may not break any venv's you have.
